# Handle concurrent http requests in Go

Tags: go, concurrency, uwsgi, wsgi, goroutine

I want to re-write an app with large amount of concurrent users. Imagine a chat app that has millions of users connected via `Websocket`. Used to I fine tune `Python`+`Django`+`UWSGI` and an architecture that worked by today. Now I see slow connections and timeouts and so on.

I decided to use `Go` language and drop Python and my question is that I couldn't find anything like UWSGI and I know Go has builtin concurrent capabilities. This means a Go server don't need something like UWSGI and can handle concurrent requests? or concurrency mentioned in go is just about simple I/O?

I need performance and concurrency in it maximum. I understand this issue well? These two are equivalent? Go can help me? and we don't need something like UWSGI and Go's core capabilities can work much faster and better in this issue?

Comment: Look at go web frameworks like go-gin, echo & martini etc. And then select whichever suits you. They have built in support for concurrent handling of requests. Furthermore, the native go-http module is also very powerful.

Comment: Go is up your alley, and the core library (`net/http`) may be sufficient (no need for framework, necessarily). Just remember that built-in concurrency doesn't give you a licence to access shared memory without proper synchronisation (risk of race conditions) and you'll be fine.

Comment: You mentioned millions of users connected via websockets. There is a good talk and code examples doing this at - Going Infinite, handling 1M websockets connections in Go https://github.com/eranyanay/1m-go-websockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at Go channels. Go channels in combination with Go routines can easily scale concurrency within the same process. Compared to Java Threading, Go routines are very efficient and have less context switching. Only 4kb mem consumption. In Go you don't share memory, but instead communicate state by pushing them on the channels, which results in no context switching to access shared memory.

Channels in Go work in a similar fashion as you would use some queuing system like Apache Kafka or RabbitMq.

I wrote an extensive example on this in following blogpost.

https://marcofranssen.nl/concurrency-in-go

If you are really new to go I can also advice to have a look at my other articles.

https://marcofranssen.nl/categories/golang

Read them from old to new to get familiar with the language after doing the quick start tutorial.

Once you know about Go channels you know how to efficiently implement the internal logic. For the external facing API I would choose https://grpc.io/ which allows to communicate on the TCP level. It allows to do streaming implementations in both directions.

Comment: Thanks @Marco. Im very new to Go and I want to re-write the whole system. You'r answer is very clear, but I just one another question so I can choose what I have to do. In my old model, Nginx sends requests to multiple workers created by uWSGI and each of them do their job. each of them is a complete copy of the system, so we avoid bottleneck.  In Go Web server will deliver request to one single code, and that one code will use concurrency to do the job. My goal is to avoid bottlenecks. As my understanding of Go, there will be no any problem and this goal will meet so much better. Am I right?

Comment: If you expose a REST api or a GRPC api you can still deploy multiple instances of your API behind nginx (Nginx also supports TCP load balancing). However you probably need less instances as a single deployment will be able to handle more requests. Also if you choose gRPC, you will figure faster api experience as opposed to REST due to smaller payloads and TCP level communication.